# Rails: Creating a record with HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, new-operator, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've been doing this to create a record with a HABTM relationship:

```
@project = Project.new(:title => params[:project][:title],
                       :percent_complete => params[:project][:percent_complete])
@project.users << User.find(params[:project][:users])
```

I was wondering if there's a way to do the same thing, but more succinctly like this:

```
@project = Project.new(:title => params[:project][:title],
                       :percent_complete => params[:project][:percent_complete]
                       :users => User.find(params[:project][:users]))
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into using [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in your Project model. I think it should do what you're looking for. To be honest though, I don't think it will buy you much and may complicate things more than you want.

Comment: Yea, you're right...the extra line is not that big a deal then.  Thanks!